# Java ui4j. Can't find element to submit

Tags: java, web-scraping, ui4j

I have the following:
Login textbox....

```
<input type="text" class="form-control" id="usr" value="">
```

Password textbox..

```
<input type="password" class="form-control" id="pwd" value="">
```

Login button......

```
<button type="submit" class="sc-gZMcBi btn btn-primary jcDsfy">Login</button>
```

I am able to send text to login and password textbox, but I can't find the button to submit.
here is my code...

```
doc.query("input[id='usr']")
        .setValue("xxxx");
try { Thread.sleep(2000); } catch (InterruptedException ex) { }

doc.query("input[id='pwd']").setValue("yyyyyy");

try { Thread.sleep(2000); } catch (InterruptedException ex) { }

doc.query("sc-gZMcBi btn btn-primary jcDsfy").focus().click();
```

I have been trying changing the last part with differents values and using submit() and others, but getting always NULL element.

The code I am trying to scrape is like this:

```
<body style="margin: 0;">
  <div id="app">
     <div data-reactroot="">
         <header>
             <div class="sc-htpNat giiXMO sc-bwzfXH boSKPF">
                 <svg viewBox="0 0 100 20" width="250px" height="50px" class="sc-bdVaJa fXhIFv"><path fill="#FFF" d="M23.8 14.3L21 10.6h-1.1v3.7h-3.3V4.6h4.9c3.6 0 5.9 1 5.9 3 0 1.4-1.3 2.2-3.1 2.7l3.2 4h-3.7zm-2.5-8h-1.5V9h1.6c1.7 0 2.6-.5 2.6-1.3.1-1-.7-1.4-2.7-1.4zM35.6 10.6v3.7h-3.3v-3.6l-4.8-6.1h3.6l1.4 2c.6.8 1.2 1.8 1.4 2.3.2-.5.8-1.5 1.4-2.3l1.4-2h3.6l-4.7 6zM48.1 14.3l-.9-2h-4.1l-.9 2h-3.4l4.7-9.7h3.2l4.7 9.7h-3.3zM46 9.5c-.3-.7-.7-1.9-.9-2.4-.1.5-.5 1.5-.8 2.3l-.5 1.2h2.7L46 9.5zM60.5 14.3L57.1 10c-.5-.6-1.1-1.4-1.4-2 0 .6.1 1.6.1 2.2v4.1h-3V4.6h3.3l3.2 4.3c.4.6 1.1 1.5 1.5 2 0-.6-.1-1.7-.1-2.3v-4h3v9.7h-3.2zM74.3 14.3l-.9-2h-4.1l-.9 2H65l4.7-9.7H73l4.7 9.7h-3.4zm-2.1-4.8c-.3-.7-.7-1.9-.9-2.4-.1.5-.5 1.5-.8 2.3l-.5 1.2h2.7l-.5-1.1zM79 14.3V4.6h3.3v9.7H79zM92.4 14.3l-2.9-3.7h-1.1v3.7h-3.3V4.6H90c3.6 0 5.9 1 5.9 3 0 1.4-1.3 2.2-3.1 2.7l3.2 4h-3.6zm-2.5-8h-1.5V9H90c1.7 0 2.6-.5 2.6-1.3.1-1-.7-1.4-2.7-1.4z"></path><g fill="#F1C931"><path d="M11.2 4.2c.7.2 1.4.4 2.1.5h.5c.3 0 .5-.1.8-.2h.1c0 .1 0 .1-.1.2-.4.3-.8.5-1.2.6-.1 0-.3.1-.4.1-.5.2-1.1.2-1.6.2-1-.1-1.9-.4-2.9-.4-.9-.1-1.8.3-2.3 1-.1.4-.3.8-.3 1.2 0 .4.6.5.8.8l.3.6c.1.4.3.8.6 1.2.2.2.4.5.7.6.4.3.7.6.9 1 .2.4.4.7.5 1.1.1.2.2.4.2.7v.1c.1.2.1.4.2.5v.1c0 .1.1.3 0 .3-.2-.2-.3-.4-.4-.6-.1-.4-.4-.8-.7-1.2-.2-.2-.4-.5-.6-.7-.8-.9-2-1.5-2.9-2.3 0 0 0-.1-.1-.2-.1-.2-.2-.3-.3-.5-.2-.4-.5-.8-.7-1.3 0-.2-.1-.4-.1-.6v-.1c0-.2-.5-.3-.2-.7.2-.2.8-.4 1-.8v-.2s0-.1-.1-.1-.4.2-.4-.1v-.3c.1-.2.1-.4.1-.6 0-.1.1-.1.2-.1s.3-.1.4-.1c.3 0 .7 0 .9.2.1.2 0 .4 0 .6 0 .2-.2.3-.1.4h.2c.4-.3.8-.7 1.2-1.1.3-.3.8-.4 1.2-.3.9 0 1.6.3 2.5.5z"></path><path d="M8.9 5.8c.1.2 0 .3-.1.5-.5.7-.7 1.6-1 2.4h-.1c-.1 0-.1-.1-.1-.2 0-.9.3-1.7.7-2.5.1-.1.2-.3.4-.2.1-.1.1 0 .2 0zM10.3 6c.1.3-.1.5-.2.8-.5 1-1.1 2-1.4 3.1 0 0 0 .1-.1.1h-.1c-.1-.4 0-.9.1-1.3.3-.9.6-1.8 1.1-2.7.1 0 .1-.1.1-.1.2 0 .4 0 .5.1zM11.7 6.1c.1.1.1.3 0 .4-.6 1.3-1.5 2.4-1.9 3.8l-.3.9c0 .1-.1.1-.1 0-.1-.1 0-.3 0-.4.1-1.1.4-2.2.9-3.1.2-.5.5-.9.7-1.4.1-.1.2-.3.4-.3.1 0 .2 0 .3.1zM13.3 6.2c.1.2 0 .3 0 .5-.4 1-1.1 1.9-1.6 2.9-.5.8-.8 1.7-1.1 2.5-.1.3-.2.5-.3.8h-.1c-.1-.1-.1-.2-.1-.3.1-1.1.5-2 .9-3 .5-1.1 1.1-2.1 1.6-3.2.1-.1.2-.3.4-.4.1 0 .2 0 .3.2z"></path></g></svg>
                    <label class="sc-bxivhb cuNflP">XXX</label>
                       </div>
                       <div class="sc-ifAKCX kJuBmr sc-bwzfXH boSKPF"></div>
         </header>
         <form class="sc-iwsKbI ehzITl"><div class="form-group"><label for="usr">Username:</label><input type="text" class="form-control" id="usr" value=""></div><div class="form-group"><label for="pwd">Password:</label><input type="password" class="form-control" id="pwd" value=""></div><div id="spinner"></div><button type="submit" class="sc-gZMcBi btn btn-primary jcDsfy">Login</button><label class="sc-gqjmRU goeyjb"></label></form>
         <!-- react-empty: 54 -->
         <!-- react-empty: 70 -->
         <!-- react-empty: 23 -->
     </div>
  </div>
  <script src="bundle.js"></script>
</body>
```

Comment: Try: `doc.query(".sc-gZMcBi .btn .btn-primary .jcDsfy").focus().click();`

Comment: Thanks Lino, but is the same. I updated the code, maybe you can see something else.